# getLinks method returns deleted Entities, how to prevent it?

Tags: java, xodus

Below is my code to get the list of `Entity`'s linked. It works but the problem is that even the deleted `Entity` is returned, although the `Entity` is already emptied out and it is the only property set. Is there a way to not return the deleted entities at all? Or is there a way to filter it out?

```
EntityId idOfEntity = txn.toEntityId(entityId);
Entity txnEntity = txn.getEntity(idOfEntity);
EntityIterable result = txnEntity.getLinks(Arrays.asList(new String[] {linkName}));
for (Entity entity : result) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete an entity, it's your responsibility to check if there are incoming links to the deleted entity. Otherwise so called "phantom links" can appear. You can set `-Dexodus.entityStore.debug.searchForIncomingLinksOnDelete=true` (`PersistentEntityStoreConfig#setDebugSearchForIncomingLinksOnDelete(true)`) to debug deletion in your application. With this setting, Xodus searches for incoming links to each deleted entity and throws `EntityStoreException` if it finds. The setting should not be used in production environment as it significantly slows down entity deletion performance.

Comment: Thanks for this I have managed to fix the issue (bug) although I understand that there is a performance penalty for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete code that I have come up with:

```
@Override
  public boolean deleteEntities(String instance, String namespace, final String entityType) {
    final boolean[] success = {false};
    final PersistentEntityStore entityStore = manager.getPersistentEntityStore(xodusRoot, instance);
    try {
      entityStore.executeInTransaction(
          new StoreTransactionalExecutable() {
            @Override
            public void execute(@NotNull final StoreTransaction txn) {
              EntityIterable result = null;
              if (namespace != null && !namespace.isEmpty()) {
                result =
                    txn.findWithProp(entityType, namespaceProperty)
                        .intersect(txn.find(entityType, namespaceProperty, namespace));
              } else {
                result =
                    txn.getAll(entityType).minus(txn.findWithProp(entityType, namespaceProperty));
              }
              final boolean[] hasError = {false};
              for (Entity entity : result) {

                entity.getLinkNames().forEach(linkName -> {
                  Entity linked = entity.getLink(linkName);
                  entity.deleteLink(linkName, linked);
                });


                // TODO: This is a performance issue
                final List<String> allLinkNames = ((PersistentEntityStoreImpl) entityStore).getAllLinkNames((PersistentStoreTransaction) entityStore.getCurrentTransaction());
                for (final String entityType : txn.getEntityTypes()) {
                  for (final String linkName : allLinkNames) {
                    for (final Entity referrer : txn.findLinks(entityType, entity, linkName)) {
                      referrer.deleteLink(linkName, entity);
                    }
                  }
                }

                if (!entity.delete()) {
                  hasError[0] = true;
                }
              }
              success[0] = !hasError[0];
            }
          });
    } finally {
      // entityStore.close();
    }

    return success[0];
  }
```